# Простая .htaccess переадресация на нужную директорию

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Привет всем. 
Прошу вашей помощи в поиске ошибки, допущенной в .htaccess
Задача очень простая - есть сайт test-site на локальном сервере. В корне лежат папка public_html и файлик .htaccess. Внутри public_html два файла index.html, test-page.html.

Какие правила прописать в .htaccess чтобы при заходе на test-site/index.html происходил редирект на test-site/public_html/index.html. Аналогично с test-site/test-page.html.

Пробую делать так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) public_html/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Но происходит нечто похожее на рекурсию - строка url принимает вид test-site/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/ а соединение сбрасывается.

Казалось бы - все просто, но уже пол дня мучаюсь не могу найти ошибку.
Помогите понять где ошибка.

UPD:
Только что нашел ошибку:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) folder1/$1 [L]
```

Нужно было дописать
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Может кому то будет полезным: http://www.remoteshaman.com/server/apache/mod-rewrite-explanation-and-tips 
Очень наглядно и детально про mod-rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Я вот не понимаю, для чего вам такой велосипед? не проще ли, прописать в файле index.html простую переадресацию, и не засорять свой разум, всякими костылями. Либо я что-то не так понял.

UPD: http://www.itlessons.info/php/routing-library/

Comment: Ну это же не просто одна страница в folder1 могут лежать 100 страниц. Для каждой прописывать редирект не вариант.
И захочу перенести сайт в folder2 - снова переписывать 100 страниц.

Comment: ну предположим, что есть index.html
и есть 99 страниц которые будут открываться при переходе на index.html

Как ты себе это можешь представить?

Comment: Не, такого я конечно представить не могу. Я имел в виду что есть страницы index.html, about_us.html, contact.html, и т.д.
Переходя на index.html будет открываться index.html, переходя на about_us.html будет открываться about_us.html.
Я не имел в виду что нужно сделать одну точку входа через редирект..

Comment: @Mescalito1990 если бы вы написали, сразу то что вы хотите сделать одну точку входа

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
RedirectMatch (.*\.html)$ http://site.ru/public_html/$1
```

Comment: Попробовал так, аналогичная ситуация.
Так же пытаюсь зайти на http://test-site/public_html/index.html напрямую и срабатывает правило .htaccess с предыдущей директории - снова вижу test-site/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/ 

Может проблема в том что тестирую на Denwer?

UPD:
Только что нашел ошибку:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) folder1/$1 [L]

Нужно было дописать
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: Я не пойму одного: зачем иметь папку public_html на локальном сервере ?

Comment: Я хочу разобраться с mod_rewrite. Это тестовая задача.

Comment: >зачем иметь папку public_html на локальном сервере ?

Например, чтобы не иметь отличий в структуре каталогов на локальном сервере (разработка) и боевом (деплой).

Answer (score 0):

у меня работает так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) ./documents/public/$1
```